# Performance problems when running Wireguard between virtual machines

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtual-machine, kvm, wireguard

I’m running into performance problems with Wireguard tunnels running between two virtual machines on the same hypervisor (running under Qemu/KVM) and I would greatly appreciate any insights/advice with this problem. The problem I’m having is that various benchmarks show that the speed of the wireguard connection/tunnel is about 80-90% slower than the speed of the ‘normal’ network connection that wireguard is running over. The Wireguard config is a simple point-to-point configuration.

The same Wireguard configuration between two physical computers runs just fine and only results in a performance lost of about 4-5%. Which leads me to believe that the problem is in the virtualization layer somewhere. I have tried many things already with no positive results:

- Increasing CPU & RAM of the VMs has no effect.
- Testing performance of encryption/decryption tasks  on these VMs show no significant performance hit. So CPU performance seems to be fine for these VMs.
- Virtualization support for the CPU is enabled in the hypervisor BIOS
- I tried out some different MTU sizes with no real difference.
- CPU pinning and various CPU settings inside Qemu/KVM make no difference.
- Wireguard is running in kernel mode
- I run into the same problems with the same setup on different machines/hypervisor combinations (VirtualBox, for example) which leads to me to believe I’m somehow doing something wrong configuration wise. Everything that runs on virtual machines seems to have this problem.
- Different Linux distributions also seem to make no difference

Here is some more info about my setup and a benchmark. The two virtual machines are called wireguard-client-01 and wireguard-server:

**wireguard-client-01 network info:**

```
[root@wireguard-client-01 ~]# ip a
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:d4:fa:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.41/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft 863813sec preferred_lft 863813sec
    inet6 fd00::5054:ff:fed4:fa89/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 7021sec preferred_lft 3421sec
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fed4:fa89/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.2/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**wireguard-server network info:**

```
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:73:c2:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.40/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft 863677sec preferred_lft 863677sec
    inet6 fd00::5054:ff:fe73:c26d/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 6880sec preferred_lft 3280sec
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe73:c26d/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.1/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**wireguard-server wg0 config:**

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.1/24
SaveConfig = true
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = <my_private_key>

[Peer]
PublicKey = E0eS7oBffTDg8Qj4ZeIUhxA0GUC3HrSfacrjP54hFQI=
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.2/32
Endpoint = 192.168.2.41:48671
```

**Wireguard-client-01 wg0 config:**

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <my_private_key>
Address = 10.8.0.2/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = h+kDKK/2Y+WXRiO9lSQ0RT3HsRi0m6OckOkEJep/2jM=
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.0/24
Endpoint = 192.168.2.40:51820
```

**iperf3 benchmarks over 'normal' network interfaces:**

```
[root@wireguard-client-01 ~]# iperf3 --client 192.168.2.40                                                                                                                                                         
Connecting to host 192.168.2.40, port 5201                                                                                                                                                                         
[  5] local 192.168.2.41 port 57836 connected to 192.168.2.40 port 5201                                                                                                                                            
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd                                                                                                                                                   
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec   913 MBytes  7.66 Gbits/sec    2   3.11 MBytes                                                                                                                                            
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec   956 MBytes  8.00 Gbits/sec    2   3.11 MBytes                                                                                                                                            
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec   958 MBytes  8.05 Gbits/sec    5   3.11 MBytes                                                                                                                                            
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  1.05 GBytes  9.00 Gbits/sec    3   3.11 MBytes                                                                                                                                            
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec   998 MBytes  8.37 Gbits/sec    5   3.11 MBytes                                                                                                                                            
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  1014 MBytes  8.50 Gbits/sec    4   3.11 MBytes                                                                                                                                            
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  1.02 GBytes  8.75 Gbits/sec    4   3.11 MBytes                                                                                                                                            
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec   960 MBytes  8.06 Gbits/sec    5   3.11 MBytes                                                                                                                                            
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  1.17 GBytes  10.0 Gbits/sec    2   3.11 MBytes                                                                                                                                            
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  1022 MBytes  8.58 Gbits/sec    3   3.11 MBytes                                                                                                                                            
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -                                                                                                                                                                  
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr                                                                                                                                                         
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  9.90 GBytes  8.50 Gbits/sec   35             sender                                                                                                                                       
[  5]   0.00-10.03  sec  9.89 GBytes  8.47 Gbits/sec                  receiver                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
iperf Done.
```

**iperf3 benchmarks over wireguard tunnel (note the difference in bitrate drops by about 80%):**

```
[root@wireguard-client-01 ~]# iperf3 --client 10.8.0.1
Connecting to host 10.8.0.1, port 5201
[  5] local 10.8.0.2 port 39384 connected to 10.8.0.1 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec   125 MBytes  1.05 Gbits/sec  106   1.59 MBytes       
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec   120 MBytes  1.01 Gbits/sec    0   1.74 MBytes       
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec   132 MBytes  1.11 Gbits/sec    0   1.83 MBytes       
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec   176 MBytes  1.48 Gbits/sec   22   1.40 MBytes       
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec   221 MBytes  1.85 Gbits/sec    0   1.50 MBytes       
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec   191 MBytes  1.61 Gbits/sec    0   1.58 MBytes       
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  42.5 MBytes   357 Mbits/sec    0   1.58 MBytes       
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec   191 MBytes  1.60 Gbits/sec    0   1.65 MBytes       
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec   194 MBytes  1.63 Gbits/sec  169   1.21 MBytes       
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec   214 MBytes  1.79 Gbits/sec    0   1.36 MBytes       
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.57 GBytes  1.35 Gbits/sec  297             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.04  sec  1.57 GBytes  1.34 Gbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice about this problem and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I think iperf3 should warn about fragmentation, but, just to be sure, as that's been my nr 1 headache with wg: try specifying a safe MTU in the wireguard configs, something like 1400 for the beginning (later, you should, anyways try to up the MTU of the virtual interfaces; no reason for it to be only 1500)

Comment: I've tried several MTU settings but it either makes the connection go even slower or remain somewhat the same. I'm not sure if a higher MTU would make the problem better. I've tried two setups so far, one with virtual interfaces connected to a pysical one via a bridge interface. And one where the interfaces are purely virtual (the internal network that Qemu/KVM has installed out of the box). Both give the same problems.

The problem is rather confusing and so far I can't tell if this is because of a missing/wrong wireguard config or some config missing somewhere in the virtualization layer.

Comment: Guess I'll have to see if I can find any useful logging. If I find the solution than I'll report back!

Comment: Generally, you want "hardware" MTUs on virtual links to be large - there's some overhead every time you move data or if one VM into the other (unless that is done with DMA / iommu these days, which would kind of surprise me) so the fewer packets for the same data, the better